# Questions about the Data Model in MVC (iPhone)

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I wonder 4 questions about the data model when creating iOS apps:

Do you create a class called DataModel and inside there we find arrays and objects that belong to the data model that is instantiated by every model? Or do you create a data model that is a singleton and has the app state? I guess singleton is not a good idea because is difficult to test.

Where do you write your networking code and mapping code (converting json files into data model objects)? I guess it should be an object inside the data model.

I understand the model encapsulates app state, for that reasonI I guess if we have a table in controller A and the detail in controller B (using a navigation controller), maybe we have to create an instance of the data model that holds ‘selectedStudent’ and then once the B controller is pushed, it uses the model to know what student was selected. 
That’s what I understand from this image:
http://naikom.ru/img/2012/ios2/8.jpg
However from this image;
https://littlehales.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/mvc2.jpg
I see that there are several models and controllers communicate each other, so in my example, using prepareForSegue I could pass the selectedStudent to the other controller. If we do that, then the controller is encapsulating state, rather than the model.
Can you explain to me how I should do that? Or how do large apps do this?

According to this diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psi8i.png
In order to send information from the data model to the controller we have to use NSNotificationCenter or KVO.
I know the problem of delegates is that they are just a 1-to-1 relationship, so probably not good idea. What about blocks or creating your own observer using a protocol and addObserver/removeObserver (using an array or a set)? Do you really use for this NSNotificationCenter or KVO in the data model?

Comment: There are sone good books available, that's the best bet. Choose an author who is an accepted and proven developer by his/her peers. I doubt that you will get an answer here, there are to many views on code. Some say: "Every time a singleton is written a kitten dies" and note that 'NSFileManager` is a singleton. Singletons can be written that are testable and not all singletons restrict instantiation to one instance for among other reasons testability. Bjarne Stroustrup stated that delegation was difficult to understand and didn't see a use case, Cocoa used them heavly. There is no one answer.

Comment: Thanks @zaph. I agree with you. I tried the book "Pro Objective-C Design Patterns for IOS" which is really good, but regarding that topic I don't have a clear answer. Do you recommend me some books? Thanks.

Comment: Here are four references: [*Implementation Patterns*](http://www.amazon.com/Implementation-Patterns-Kent-Beck/dp/0321413091) by Kent Beck. [*Design Patterns*](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented-ebook/dp/B000SEIBB8/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1442956204&sr=1-1&keywords=design+patterns) by the Gang of Four [*Clean Code*](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=clean+code) by Robert Martin. [Clean Coders](http://cleancoders.com/category/clean-code) videos by Uncle Bob (Episode 1 is free online).